# Viewing ServicePulse from another machine

Tags: nservicebus

I have ServicePulse running on my production Worker machine, the one that does all the processing of my NServiceBus endpoints.

When I'm remoted in to that machine, and I browse to http://localhost:9090, the data I see is as expected.

However, when use the browser on my developer machine, and I browse to http://[workerIPhere]:9090, I get the ServicePulse page loaded, but the info I'm seeing is as per developer endpoints I have running on my local developer machine.

When I use the browser on some random client on the network, one that has no NServiceBus or ServicePulse or ServiceControl assets installed, and I browse to http://[workerIPhere]:9090, I get a ServicePulse page loaded, but there is no info about endpoints at all, and the latest events "loading" icon just keeps spinning and spinning.

So it seems that even though I'm browsing to my Production Server's ServicePulse page, the data it's displaying seems to always be from the local machine.  What am I missing?  I don't want to have to remote in to the production server in order to see it's ServicePulse information.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServicePulse is a java script application designed to run against a local ServiceControl instance.

The reason you are seeing your development ServiceControl data is because your browser is using the default configuration to talk to your local development ServiceControl.

If you have access to your production service control ip address from your development desktop machine you can change the configuration to monitor your production system.

- Stop the ServicePulse service on your Production Server
- Then go to the installation path, usually here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServicePulse\`.
- If you are using the latest version of ServicePulse you will find a file called `app\js\app.constants.js`
- Edit the `service_control_url: 'http://localhost:33333/api'` to be `'service_control_url: 'http://YOUR_PROD_ServiceControl_IP_ADDRESS:33333/api'`
- Start the ServicePulse Service again and all should be good.

There is more documentation [here](http://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/introduction-and-installing-servicepulse)

I hope this helps